# Any better way to detect Signal with ADC Overflow problem?

Tags: signal-analysis, python, analog-to-digital

I am trying to create an algorithm to detect signal with "ADC overflow" as shown in picture on lower right. It happened because someone had incorrectly down converted an int16 signal into int8 signal. The sampling rate of the signal was 1000Hz, about 2 minutes in duration and has bandwidth up to 300Hz due to low pass filtering. I have few thousands of them and the "ADC overflow" could happen at any place. I need to quickly identify those signal and their overflow locations.

So far I use this technique but it is not robust enough, because I have to keep lowering the threshold=0.8 for higher frequency signal. It's also very hard to differentiate random noise from ADC overflow. Does anyone has better way to do this? Thanks

```
# Python
# y = int8 signal with ADC overflow as shown on the right
diff = np.abs( np.diff( y.astype(np.int64) ) ) / 255
overflow_loc = (diff >= 0.8)   # <-- 0.8 may not work for high freq signal
overflow_loc += np.roll(overflow_loc, 1)
loc = np.where(overflow_loc == 1)[0]
```

[image: Overflow Int8]

---

Ok I tried the Histogram method, but I still can not tell the different. Here is my Python code and output. Please enlighten...

```
freq = 10
x = np.linspace(0, 1.0 / freq, 256)
y = 1.1 * 127 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * x)
yo = y.astype(np.int8)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

axs[0, 0].plot(x, y)
axs[0, 0].set_yticks([-128, 127])
axs[0, 0].plot(x, [-128] * len(x), '-.')
axs[0, 0].plot(x, [127] * len(x), '--')
axs[0, 0].set_title('ideal signal (np.float64)')

axs[0, 1].hist(y, bins=200)
axs[0, 1].set_title('amplitude histogram (ideal signal)')

axs[1, 0].plot(x, yo)
axs[1, 0].set_yticks([-128, 127])
axs[1, 0].plot(x, [-128] * len(x), '-.')
axs[1, 0].plot(x, [127] * len(x), '--')
axs[1, 0].set_title('overflow signal (np.int8)')

axs[1, 1].hist(yo, bins=200)
axs[1, 1].set_title('amplitude histogram (overflow signal)')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried an amplitude histogram? Clipping puts horns at the extremes

Comment: not yet, but how does it works? please enlighten

Comment: for example, both [10, 266] are interpreted as [10,10] in the final int8 signal

Comment: How does a histogram work? or how does the pdf of clipped Gaussian noise look like?

Comment: do you have some sort of PSD of your signal of interest? If possible, one without your numeric wraparound and one with?

Comment: BTW, twos-complement fixed-point arithmetic overflow does that.  it wraps around.  but ADCs (i presume you mean analog-to-digital converters) do not wrap around.  they saturate instead.

Comment: Can you tell us the lowest and highest frequency present in the signal of interest? I'm assuming it will either be a lowpass, highpass, or bandpass signal. For signals with a white spectrum, this would be fairly difficult if not impossible. Your current method targets lowpass signals. Are you looking for an alternative targeting highpass signals as well?

Comment: The signal has bandwidth from 0.05 - 200Hz. Highest freq = 2Hz.

Answer (score 2):

How do you transform overflowed signal back to normal? Just by adding or subtracting multiplies of 256. So with every new sample you just determine whether overflow occured - you need to define some threshold and compare it with first derivative of your signal, e.g. `x[i+1]-x[i] > 200`. If this happened, you know that you need to subtract 256 from x[i+1] to get continuous signal. Opposite case `x[i+1]-x[1] < -200` means that you need to add 256. So the pseudocode would be:

```
base = 0
thresh = 200
for each i in x
  d = x[i] - x[i-1]
  if d > thresh then base = base - 256
  if d < -thresh then base = base + 256
  y[i] = x[i] + base
next
```

Comment: But your image reminds me well known problem of incorrect handling signed/unsigned values. These overflows happen when you save the recording as unsigned ints and then read them as signed (or vice versa)

Comment: But your image reminds me well known problem of incorrect handling signed/unsigned values. These overflows happen when you save the recording as unsigned ints and then read them as signed (or vice versa)

Comment: Take a look here, you are just not handling the samples correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521857/strange-sine-wave-on-output-of-an-alsa-linux-c-program